# Remove Gutenberg Buttons Block

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor, buttons

Is there a way to remove the default core/buttons block in Gutenberg, or other various blocks? We're creating our own buttons block and don't want the user to get it confused with the default one and would rather just remove it altogether.

I've tried the following but it tells me that $allowed_block_types is a bool and not an array.

```php
function hide_default_button_block($allowed_block_types, $post) {
    // Remove the default Gutenberg button block
    if ($post->post_type === 'post' || $post->post_type === 'page') {
        $allowed_block_types = array_diff($allowed_block_types, ['core/button']);
    }

    return $allowed_block_types;
}

add_filter('allowed_block_types', 'hide_default_button_block', 10, 2);
```

I'm trying to do this in just a theme currently, but will need to implement this in a plugin eventually that will replace core blocks with our revised ones.

Answer (score 0):

This added to the functions.php allows the removal of specific Gutenberg blocks.

```php
function hide_default_blocks($allowed_block) {
    $blocks = WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered();

    unset($blocks['core/buttons']);

    return array_keys($blocks);
}

add_filter('allowed_block_types_all', 'hide_default_blocks');
```

Part of the issue is that it is `core/buttons` and not `core/button` but also the method of removal was incorrect.